# How to pass and access Dataproc Sparkjob args while instantiating the Dataproc Workflow Template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parameter-passing, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using Dataproc Workflow Template to run the Sparkjob. I want to pass the input file dynamically to the Sparkjob args while instantiating it through Dataproc Workflow Template. How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Parameterization of Dataproc Workflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/workflow-parameters).

Example template (`my_template.yaml`):

```
...
jobs:
  - stepId: job1
    sparkJob:
      ...
      args:
      - 'input file URI'
      - 'output directory'
parameters:
- name: INPUT_FILE
  fields:
  - jobs['job1'].sparkJob.args[0]
- name: OUTPUT_DIR
  fields:
  - jobs['job1'].sparkJob.args[1]
```

Create/import the template:

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates import my-template \
    --region=<region> \
    --source=my_template.yaml
```

Instantiate the template with args:

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate my-template \
    --region=<region> \
    --parameters=INPUT_FILE=gs://my-bucket/test.txt,OUTPUT_DIR=gs://my-bucket/output/
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I made a slight correction in the YAML file and gcloud command to make it work.

**YAML file** --> args index will be 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2

**gcloud command** --> we have to mention the region

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I fixed it.